# Protocol implementation between subview

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have a main view where I add a subview. I would like to trigger an event from the subview and catch the event in the main view.. So I used protocol implementation but I don't receive the message from the HomeViewController. Why ?

**Protocol**

```
protocol MyDetectionDelegate : class {
    func somethingDiscovered(_ message : String )
}
```

**Main View**

```
class HomeViewController : UIViewController, MyDetectionDelegate {


 var childView : DetectionView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        childView = DetectionView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        childView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(childView)
        childView.autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdges(with: UIEdgeInsets.zero)

    }

 func somethingDiscovered(_ message: String) {
         print("Hi I discovered something : \(message)")
 }

}
```

**Child View :**

```
class DetectionView: UIView {

   // Delegation
   weak var delegate : MyDetectionDelegate?

   // Functions
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        ....

        iDiscoveredSomething()
   }

   func iDiscoveredSomething(){

        delegate?.somethingDiscovered("5 potatoes")

   }

}
```

Comment: You can not detect it due to you calling your delegate method before referencing delegate to HomeViewController.

Comment: Ok I add some NSLog and you seems to be right. Seams to be a bad practice to call delegate function inside the init function of this viewchild

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initiate your UIView like this:

```
class  DetectionView: UIView {

var delegate: MyDetectionDelegate!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

convenience init(mainController: MyDetectionDelegate){
self.init()
delegate = mainController
// Write all the initiation codes here.

delegate.somethingDiscovered("Hello")
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

In the Controller class, initiate the view like this:

```
 var detectionView = DetectionView.init(mainController: self)
```

Add a frame to it or do AutoLayout by code as you like to the view.

The solution is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Why are you calling the delegate parameter as "controller"?

Comment: I didn't want to name the parameter "delegate" and make it confusing. And basically, since the delegate object will be the controller in which the UIView is initiated, I figured it's a good name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't see any function being fired by the delegate because the initialisation is ran first before the delegate is set (in the `HomeViewController`). So the `delegate?` reference is actually nil when you want to call `somethingDiscovered()`

Your setup is correct and the protocol pattern will work. Just not in this particular way.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here,

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    ....

    iDiscoveredSomething()
}
```

You are calling method in init of your View. So this method will go to call your protocol method via delegate reference. But delegate reference will not found and nothing happened. So my suggestion is add button in you view and try to call delegate on button's action.

Comment: I like you suggestion for my project requirement. Thank you.